# Thunderbolt 3 diagram? Bandwidth allocation?

Tags: thunderbolt, usb-c

I am trying to understand Thunderbolt 3 and I have some grasp on it: it provides a 40 gigabit per second bus which carries multiplexed signals. I am not using gbps or similar abbreviations for clarity and maximum avoidance of confusing gigabit and gigabyte, there's plenty of confusion anyways.

Some of the signals that can be on this bus are

- At most four PCI Express 3.0 lanes. I think two or four lane controllers exist. If I understand things correctly then four lanes consume 31.52 gigabit per second.
- At most eight DisplayPort 2.0 lanes. If these are supporting HBR2 then eight lanes would be 8 * 5.4 = 43.2 gigabit per second. There's support for (4096 x 2160) 30-bit @ 120 Hz or two of those at 60 Hz -- which I believe requires 38.22 gigabit per second.
- USB 3.1 Gen 2 signals at 10 gigabit per second.

So... how on earth does all of this work? Obviously you can't squeeze all of this into 40 gigabit. Even just DisplayPort + five gigabit USB alone is certainly over 40 gigabit (the theoretical bandwidht of DP is already over it). Or is the trick that the various signals are "stripped" of their various encodings so instead of HBR2 encoded DP signals at 43.2 gigabit second they only consume the video data rate at 34.56?

And Thunderbolt docks daisy chain. What happens if you plug in a 4k @ 60 Hz monitor into a dock and then daisy chain a PCIe dock...? Does it drop to x2 or doesn't work at all? Where can I read more?

Answer (score 2):

Two years later I know most of the answers thanks to the [platform brief](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/sites/default/files/Thunderbolt3_TechBrief_FINAL.pdf). The question is mistaken, there are no USB signals on the bus just PCI Express and DisplayPort. And, the way it works, DisplayPort has priority and whatever is left is used for PCIe signals -- which are capped at 22 Gbps.